# Retrieving comments from a site using Rails and Koala

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, comments, koala

I am trying to take comments from different news sites and do some processing with it. For example, https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://techcrunch.com/2012/01/04/mechanical-engineering-community-grabcad-grabs-4-million/

i have the comments but i dont know how to store it to mysql database (or any other database) using rails and koala.

Any help/tips is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Check out the code below:

```
url_commented_on = "http://techcrunch.com/2012/01/04/mechanical-engineering-community-grabcad-grabs-4-million/"
fb_comments_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids="+url_commented_on
fb_comments_json = open(fb_comments_url).read
fb_comments_data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(fb_comments_json)

# If you want to play around, this gets you the first comment
fb_comments_data[url_commented_on]["comments"]["data"].first
# and this gets you the first comment's message
fb_comments_data[url_commented_on]["comments"]["data"].first["message"]

# You could save them in your db like this:
fb_comments = fb_comments_data[url_commented_on]["comments"]["data"]
fb_comments.each do |fb_comment|
  # Your comment Model here
  fb_commenter_name = fb_comment["from"]["name"]
  fb_comment_message = fb_comment["message"]
  fb_comment_creation_date = fb_comment["created_time"]
  # Your comment Model
  comment = CommentModel.new
  comment.author = fb_commenter_name
  comment.comment_text = fb_comment_message
  # Don't overwrite your own "created_at" attribute
  # Instead, use an additional column in the db for storing the date fb gives you
  comment.fb_created_at = fb_comment_creation_date 
  comment.save!
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can parse the JSON using Ruby

```
data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(json_data)
```

and then simply iterate over the data and store it in a database using ActiveRecord

```
data["data"].each do |comment|
  Comment.create!(:message => comment.message, ...)
end
```

Comment: specially when i am trying to get it from facebook. like i dont wanna copy and paste all that text to my file. is there any efficient way of doing this by passing the link i have?